# Trying to install an IBM Workload Scheduler agent

Tags: linux, agent, workload-scheduler

I am trying to install an IBM Workload Scheduler agent version 9.4 on a machine with LINUX PPC64LE SELS 12 SP2. The installation does not work correctly and I find the following message in the /opt/IBM/TWA_twsuser/logs/result.txt log file:

The prerequisite fails because the 32 bit libraries are not available.
os.lib.libstdc.so.5_32       FAIL       Unavailable      /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5
os.lib.libstdc.so.6_32       FAIL       Unavailable      /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
os.strings.libstdc           FAIL       Unavailable      /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6:GLIBCXX_3.4.6

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 1):

You can try and restart the installation using the twsinst script and specifying the -skipcheckprereq parameter. This prevents checking for these libraries, which are not mandatory for the specific Linux version you are using.